# Apache POI java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache-poi

```js
CTTbl cttbl = technologyTable.getCTTbl();
cttbl.getInsList().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

I have trying use the function getInsList in Apache POI , but I alaways got this exception

```js
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/impl/CTTblImpl$1InsList
 at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTTblImpl.getInsList(Unknown Source)
 at com.ocean.Main.getTechnologyList(Main.java:138)
 at com.ocean.Main.main(Main.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTTblImpl$1InsList
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 3 more
```

I have already add jar file in the project including below

- poi-3.17.jar
- poi-examples-3.17.jar
- poi-excelant-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar
- commons-codec-1.10.jar
- commons-collections4-4.1.jar

What else I miss or something wrong with my code ?

Comment: As mentioned in [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025) the usage of all underlaying low level classes sometimes needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar`.

Comment: I've added this jar and all is well ,thanks for your kind assistance !

Comment: BTW , do you know how to get the last edition while the docx document had already had a lot of track changes ! I found if I get the table will mixed with the previous editions !! Could you help me or give me some tips

Comment: Simplest way: Open in `Word`and [Accept tracked changes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/accept-tracked-changes-4838d24c-d5d1-4c6c-8e39-78b44bd2b4cc), then save. Now you have a document without any `CTRunTrackChange` elements. Or for getting only the last text, get only content from `w:t` elements out of the paragraphs but not the content of `w:delText`.